# Random MSDTC errors

Tags: sql-server

We are getting below randomly from application.Same piece of code works on another server.

> > : SQL Statement Failed ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Unable to start a nested transaction for OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "server". A nested transaction was required because the XACT_ABORT option was set to OFF.

We have checked below settings

[image]

Further info

1.firewall is off
2.DTC ping works fine
3.No RPC ports entry
4.Nothing is found in DTC logs(c:\windows\system32\msdtc\trace )

We followed all the items in this check list

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2011/11/22/troubleshooting-msdtc-communication-checklist/

**ASK:**
Did any one faced Random DTC errors like above ..What can be done further to debug this issue.Only time we see this issue is when there is huge load on server due to Disk issues(or we may be wrong )

Any pointers on using additional tools/trace flags to catch this random errors